# How to send email from pjsip. Is there any default methods available for sending emails

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, pjsip

I have a pjsip project for call application.I have an external pacakges like curl.Is it possible to add an external packages to pjsip application or how to add external packages to pjsip.Is there any default methods available for sending emails. This things i want to check.please help to solve my issues.Thanks in advance.

I want to send an email from the pjsip when the device registration failed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

#define CURL_STATICLIB 

#define FROM    "princetomy12@gmail.com"
#define TO      "sangeethjohn01@gmail.com"



static const char *payload_text[] = {
    "To: " TO "\r\n",
    "From: " FROM "\r\n",
    "Subject: SMTP TLS example message\r\n",
    NULL
};

struct upload_status {
    int lines_read;
};

static size_t payload_source(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    struct upload_status *upload_ctx = (struct upload_status *)userp;
    const char *data;

    if ((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
        return 0;
    }

    data = payload_text[upload_ctx->lines_read];

    if (data) {
        size_t len = strlen(data);
        memcpy(ptr, data, len);
        upload_ctx->lines_read++;

        return len;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{

    system("pause");
    //return (int)res;
}
static int  call_send_email()
{

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
    struct upload_status upload_ctx;

    upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;


    cout << "\nstart pgm";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "princetomy12@gmail.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "********");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "google.pem");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM);
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, TO);
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, "edgE0DF.tmp"); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        cout << "check status";
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    cout << "completed execution";

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Provide some codes.

Comment: @SangeethJohn. i have some codes from stackoverflow, that is done with curl library. i have tried in my application but doesn't  work for me.

Comment: @SangeethJohn i have posted my codes.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Its C sir.Sorry.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit .any solutions

Comment: I've never used pjsip sorry

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit.this actually a c project. i want to add an email sending code in this project.i have posted my codes. that is not working actually.     #include <curl/curl.h> from an external packages like curl.

Comment: include curl library file for sending email from your project. Don't mix with PJSIP libraries. which means for registering the project uses PJSIP libraries, if it returns registration failed then use curl library to send an e-mail.

Comment: @NandhaKumar. I have included curl librarys in to pjsip.That showing build errors .sir i dont know how to include that library.please help me sir.please ping me in skype. my skype id .prince tomy

Comment: @NandhaKumar. sir please give me your skypeid.

Comment: @NandhaKumar. i have created seperated project for email sending and included that project in the pjsip project. ie i have included the header files and call my functions from the device registration failure case in pjsip. This way for solution is good.I think there is no other option to send email using inbuilt function from pjsip.

Answer (score 2):

I have created seperate project for email sending and included that project in the pjsip project. ie I have included the header files and call my functions from the device registration failure case in pjsip.I think this way for solution is better.I think there is no other option to send email using inbuilt function from pjsip.

1. created seperate project.
2. included project in the visual studio solution explorer.
3. included header files in the pjsip
4. call my method from the project in the device registration failed case.

Comment: I think we cant add external libraries into pjsip.There is some dependency issues.